# How to make references without square brackets

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

at the moment my references are disposed like this:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsAYw.png) MONG, J..... bla bla bla.

And I would like to have them on my pdf without the square brackets, like these ones in blue:

[image: references1]

[image: references2]

Thank you for the attention!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How do you generate citation call-outs at the moment? Do you use a citation management package such as `natbib` or `cite`? Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: First of all, the brackets serve a useful purpose if you want to cite a specific page or section, like this: \cite[page 12]{book}.  I have no idea how that would work with superscripts.  It's possible to come up with a 4-line hack, but there's probably some package that does this well already.  I'm surprised no one has suggested one yet.  (Well, Mico implicitly suggested natbib and cite, but not how to use them to achieve this effect.)  Maybe add some tags to your question to get the attention of the right wizards.  In fact, I'll try to do it.  I have no idea if the site will let me.

Comment: Do you mean the cross-references or the citations? Both are in blue in the image. The cross-references are in regular (non-square) brackets (US: parentheses). The citations are superscripts. Your tags suggest you mean the former, but those commenting seem to think you mean the latter. Meanwhile, your description suggests you mean the list of references/bibliography rather than either the citations or the cross-references.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated what kind of bibliography management and production system you employ, so I'll assume it's BibTeX. If that's not the case, please let me know.

If you do use BibTeX, you could load either the [cite package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cite/) or the [natbib package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/) with the option `super`, i.e., write either

```
\usepackage[super]{cite}
```

or

```
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
```

in the preamble. That way, `\cite` instructions will generate numeric-style citation call-outs that are placed in superscript positions.